# Polymer use function validation on core-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, polymer

Can someone explain me how to use the function validation of [this Polymer element](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input) (navigate to the "validate" section?

```
<core-input ... validate="test()" error="error in the input"></test>
```

Here is definition of test:

```
function test()
{
     return true;
}
```

This  way I always get some error message about: "error in the inout".

How can I make this thing work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a security precaution, Polymer in general doesn't accept JavaScript in attributes. So, `core-input` doesn't accept `validate="test()"` syntax. You would have to install the method directly onto the element, like so:

```
input.validate = function() { ... }
```

Where data-binding is supported, you can use the published `invalid` property:

```
<core-input invalid="{{inputValue | validate}}" ...
```

where `validate` is a method on the model that takes a string and returns a boolean.

For example, in an element:

```
<template>
  <core-input invalid="{{inputValue | isInvalid}}" ...
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    isInvalid: function(value) { return false; }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! one unrelated question, is it planed to make polymer work with AngularJS, without any third part lib?