# HowTo add a required indicator to paper-input

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Given the paper-input

```
<paper-input 
  floatingLabel label="Type only numbers... (floating)" 
  validate="^[0-9]*$" error="Input     is not a number!">
</paper-input>
```

How do I add some indication that the field is required to the user.

Comment: This might be a starting point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `core-input` docs https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/blob/master/core-input.html
AFAIK `paper-input` extends `core-input` therefore this should apply here too:

> - core-input also can optionally validate the value by providing it with a
> - regular expression to match against, or a validation function. The
> - "input-invalid" event is fired if the input value changes and is invalid.
> - The "invalid" property is also available for observation.

You can change your RegExp to

```
validate="^[0-9]+$"
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

> The plus tells the engine to attempt to match the preceding token once or more.

### Update

Polymer.js core-input and paper-input support a `required` attribute since a check-in at 2014-07-08. Polymer.dart paper-elements was published at 2014-06-25 and therefore doesn't support it yet. It should work after the next release of paper-elements.

```dart
<paper-input 
  floatingLabel label="Type only numbers... (floating)" 
  validate="^[0-9]*$" error="Input     is not a number!"
  required>
</paper-input>
```

It seems there is only one `error` attribute for `validate` and `required` though.

The published [paper-input demo](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html) doesn't include an example featuring `required` yet (the demo code in the GitHub repo already does) so I don't know if provides the behavior you wish for. But you could already use the `required` attribute and apply the asterisk yourself using CSS like

```dart
  * /deep/ paper-input[required] /deep/ #label::after,
  * /deep/ paper-input[required] /deep/ #floatedLabel::after {
    content: "*";
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Gunter. But the explanation does not add, for instance, an asterisk to indicate required even before an input is entered, which is what I would like to do.

Comment: Seems not to be supported the way you want to use it. You can do this with a custom `on-input-invalid="{{inputInvalidAction}}">` function or make a feature request in the core-input repo.

Comment: I think this answer is giving false information. You cannot use the core-input validation methods (either via a regex or callback function) to validate an empty input. See my bug report here: https://github.com/Polymer/core-input/issues/12

Comment: Oh, it seems I misinterpreded the question or at least the comment.

Comment: The CSS doesn't contain the selectors for browsers without native shadowDOM though (as discussed in the workaround for the BWU Datagrid background) If you need them drop a note.

Comment: At the present moment "required" has been inserted in the official demo, but it simply makes the paper input bar red. I need to add a red asterisk to the label... I tried with your CSS modification but I can't make it work...