# paper-input validate does not work

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to validate the following:

```dart
<paper-input floatinglabel
  id="ethinic-group"
  label="Ethnic Group"
  value='{{race.ethnicGroup}}'
  validate="[A-Za-z'\s-]*"
  error="Only letters, space and dash are allowed">
</paper-input>
```

If I put a number in the field, validation is not fired. Is there something else that I should add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can
- check the `invalid` attribute and for example change the appearance of the element depending on the attribute value
- listen on `on-input-invalid='{{inputInvalidHandler}}'` or `on-input-valid='{{inputValidHandler}}' and change the appearance by code

see http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input for more details.
(As far as I know paper-input builds on top of core-input)

### Update

Your regex is missing `^` and `$`

```dart
validate="^[A-Za-z'\s-]*$"
```

You had this already in [HowTo add a required indicator to paper-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572472) ;-)

See also [Taking total control of PaperInput validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730326) for an example about custom validation.

Comment: Looking at [http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-input) and its demo [http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html](http://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-input/demo.html) there shouldn't be anything else to do to get the validation. Is this old docs?